# Restore a deleted field (site column)

Tags: list, column, site-column, spfield

I had to add a Content Type to a list. The Content Type contained Site Column `Priority` which was a drop down, and the list already had. After I added the content type I removed the old Priority column from the list. Now the priority is empty for all items. Is it possible to recover the old data?

Answer (score 2):

No, not unless you have a backup of the list that you can restore. While the 2 columns might have the same name, they are different internally. This is why the data did not persist. You might be able to add the Priority field back if it was a system field, but that doesn't guarantee the values will come back.

The next time you do this, before deleting the column, you have to edit (manually or via script) the values of the new field with the values of the field being deleted. Once complete, then you can delete the old field.