# Restored Deleted List Column on SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, modern-experience, restore

Is it possible to restore a column, and data, that was deleted from a list on SharePoint Online?

If so, what are the steps to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

Deleted columns or the data of that particular do not go to the Recycle bins.

So, if you don't have its backup, then data is lost.

**Note**: You can create a support ticket with Microsoft and see if they can provide any help regarding data recovery: [Contact support for business products - Admin Help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/contact-support-for-business-products).

**Similar questions**:

1. [Recover deleted column from SharePoint 2013 list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536541/recover-deleted-column-from-sharepoint-2013-list).
2. [Restore a list column](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/2badf02d-2984-43e0-89d4-26951463eb15/restore-a-list-column).
3. [Restore a deleted field (site column)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158689/restore-a-deleted-field-site-column)